# I cant become user using su in plesk ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, root, plesk

I am stumped. I had created the user with root capability over a month ago. Right now I am needing to install some software and it will not allow me to use su or anything. The user has already been created so that is not an issue. I do not have this issue on any other server or vps. Has anyone had this issue, and if so how do you correct for this?

Here is the passwd file. my user is three from the bottom. let me know if this tells you anything. I do not know what went wrong, but doing su, sudo su did not work at all for this user. I was able to create a new user, make it root capeablitily and su to it. I was not able to go back to the origial 
The trial user I made is this

```
trial:x:1001:1010:,,,:/home/trial:/bin/bash

root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/usr/sbin/nologin
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/usr/sbin/nologin
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/usr/sbin/nologin
lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/usr/sbin/nologin
mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/usr/sbin/nologin
news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/usr/sbin/nologin
uucp:x:10:10:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/usr/sbin/nologin
proxy:x:13:13:proxy:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
backup:x:34:34:backup:/var/backups:/usr/sbin/nologin
list:x:38:38:Mailing List Manager:/var/list:/usr/sbin/nologin
irc:x:39:39:ircd:/var/run/ircd:/usr/sbin/nologin
gnats:x:41:41:Gnats Bug-Reporting System (admin):/var/lib/gnats:/usr/sbin/nologin
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
libuuid:x:100:101::/var/lib/libuuid:
syslog:x:101:104::/home/syslog:/bin/false
messagebus:x:102:106::/var/run/dbus:/bin/false
landscape:x:103:109::/var/lib/landscape:/bin/false
sshd:x:104:65534::/var/run/sshd:/usr/sbin/nologin
pollinate:x:105:1::/var/cache/pollinate:/bin/false
ubuntu:x:1000:1000:Ubuntu:/home/ubuntu:/bin/bash
mysql:x:106:111:MySQL Server,,,:/nonexistent:/bin/false
psaadm:x:999:1001:psa user:/opt/psa/admin:/bin/false
popuser:x:30:31:POP3 service user:/var/qmail/popuser:/bin/false
mhandlers-user:x:31:31:mail handlers user:/:/bin/false
sw-cp-server:x:998:998:sw-cp-server user:/var/lib/sw-cp-server:/bin/false
postfix:x:107:113::/var/spool/postfix:/bin/false
drweb:x:108:1005:Dr.Web system account:/var/drweb:/bin/false
roundcube_sysuser:x:997:1006:roundcube webmail user:/usr/share/psa-roundcube:/bin/false
horde_sysuser:x:996:1007:horde webmail user:/usr/share/psa-horde:/bin/false
nginx:x:995:997:Nginx user:/var/lib/nginx:/bin/false
bind:x:109:115::/var/cache/bind:/bin/false
psaftp:x:994:1008:anonftp psa user:/:/bin/false
myuser:x:10000:1004::/var/www/vhosts/vps17631:/bin/false
colord:x:110:117:colord colour management daemon,,,:/var/lib/colord:/bin/false
```

Comment: please switch to that user then can you please type `id` command and paste the output here?

Comment: I cant switch to the user. Thats the problem.  id sudo user
uid=10000(sudo user) gid=1004(psacln) groups=1004(psacln),27(sudo)
root@vps17631:~#

Comment: do you have a password set for your root user? what happen when you type `sudo su -`?

what is the username of root in `/etc/passwd` file?

Comment: sudo su was the second thing I tried. yes, every username on these machines that I use has a root password. This is odd. I created a user named trial. It worked, I was able to switch to it. trial@vps176313:. I then tried to switch to my user and nothing. When I try sudo su I get thisroot@vps176313:~# sudo su myuser
root@vps176313:~#

Comment: I will just create another user account with root capability since I had not installed my software. But I am very curious as to what is stopping me from switching to the user.

Comment: would you be able to add content of /etc/passwd file in your question? and more details what you tried and what went wrong please

Answer (score 0):

the reason is likely because you set the shell of that user to /bin/false

is the uid you trying to fix psaftp? if so, as root try this:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash psaftp
```

then you should be able to

```
su - psaftp
```